# How to add a specific vhost configuration when using mod_vhost_alias?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, mod-proxy

I use mod_vhost_alias because it is really easy for me to add new vhost (I just need to create a directory).

`/etc/apache2/mods-available/vhost_alias.conf`

```
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0/htdocs
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

However I need to configure a custom vhost to make use of `mod_proxy`, so I created:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite`

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName mysite.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.12:7235/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.12:7235/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

While it is working correctly for the vhost_alias configuration, when I try to request my.example.com I got a 404 (because the hostname directory doesn't exist), and well my site is correctly enabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: Create (empty) hostname directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0/htdocs` directive out of `/etc/apache2/mods-available/vhost_alias.conf`, and into the `<VirtualHost>` block in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`; you don't want it applying to everything.

Also - change your vhost definition in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite` from:

```
<VirtualHost *>
```

to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

.. and make sure you have a `NameVirtualHost *:80` directive somewhere (`ports.conf`?), so that your second vhost actually gets requests.